# How would you unit test a WebPart that extends BaseClientSideWebPart?

Tags: web-part, spfx, spfx-webparts

I want to unit test that webpart, but I am not sure how to go about it. I have around 30 properties and 50 private variables. How do I mock them? I use PnP to fetch values for the private values, but I am not sure how to mock the properties. Do you have any example? Because it's not a React component and I don't pass props, I am not sure how to go about mocking. Also, we don't use a store or anything of the sort.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to the below sample JSON to perform the mock testing.

```
"scripts": {
    ...
    "test": "jest" // instead of gulp test
  },
  ...
 "devDependencies": {
   ...
    "@types/jest": "22.2.3",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "ts-jest": "22.4.5",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.6.2",
   ...
  },
  "jest": {
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "ts",
      "tsx",
      "js"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.(ts|tsx)$": "ts-jest"
    },
    "testMatch": [
      "**/src/**/*.test.+(ts|tsx|js)"
    ],
    "collectCoverage": true,
    "coverageReporters": [
      "json",
      "lcov",
      "text",
      "cobertura"
    ],
    "coverageDirectory": "<rootDir>/jest",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "testResultsProcessor": "jest-junit",
    "coverageThreshold": {
      "global": {
        "branches": 100,
        "functions": 100,
        "lines": 100,
        "statements": 100
      }
    }
  }
  ....
```

You can refer to the below article which has video as well, how we can perform unit testing with mock JSON in SPFx.

[Unit Test your SharePoint Framework solution with Jest](https://blog.velingeorgiev.com/unit-test-your-sharepoint-framework-solution-with-jest)